# Prettyphoto changing lightbox height and width

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, prettyphoto

I am trying to modify the height and width of the image box that opens when I click on a thumbnail but have not had any success.

This is my code so far

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.count; i++)
{
    <a href= "@Url.Action("GetImage", "Image", new { id = i })" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]">
    <img src= "@Url.Action("GetImage", "Image", new { id = i })" alt="Image @(i+1)" width="240" height="240" /></a>
}    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            autoplay_slideshow: false,
            show_title: true,
            default_width: 300, //I have tried playing with these values
            default_height: 200, //I have tried playing with these values
            theme: 'pp_default',
            overlay_gallery: false,                  
            social_tools: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried too, but same no luck.

So did some cheating :)

Check `PrettyPhoto.css` file `/css/prettyPhoto.css` Search for `div.pp_pic_holder` and apply required width with `!important`

```
Ex.width: 825px !important;
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2):

In `jquery.prettyPhoto.js`, you should modify the following variables:

```
imageWidth = v-200;  // change to -30
imageHeight = d-200; // change to -90
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use allow_resize: false, it will display your original image size after click. for thumbnail image you need to use CSS class

**allow_resize: false**, /* Resize the photos bigger than viewport. true/false */

try this. this is how i got it working for me =)

Answer (score 0):

Simple method easily control using css

```
div.pp_pic_holder { width: 300px!important; }
.pp_content { width: 275px!important; }
a.pp_close { right: 60%; }
div.pp_pic_holder { left: 40%!important; }
```